# Java DES Encrypt/Decrypt methods

Tags: java, encryption, des

I need to create two simple methods for string DES encryption/decruption. The goal is to have these two methods in the following form

public static String desEcnrypt(String key, String clearMessage)
{
    .....
}

public static String desDecrypt(String key, String encryptedMessage)
{
    .....
}

I haven't found yet any example in this form.

Comment: Most examples use arrays of bytes because that is what encryption algorithms operate on, not strings.  You can simply convert between the bytes and an encoding of your choice, however.  Also, don't use DES, AES is superior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "not-yet-commons-ssl.jar" from http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/.

http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/pbe.html

PBE code example (DES-3):*

```
char[] password = {'c','h','a','n','g','e','i','t'};
byte[] data = "Hello World!".getBytes();

// Encrypt!
byte[] encrypted = OpenSSL.encrypt("des3", password, data);
System.out.println("ENCRYPTED: [" + new String(encrypted) + "]");

// Decrypt results of previous!
data = OpenSSL.decrypt("des3", password, encrypted);
System.out.println("DECRYPTED: [" + new String(data) + "]");


OUTPUT:
=======================
ENCRYPTED: [U2FsdGVkX19qplb9qVDVVEYxH8wjJDGpMS+F4/2pS2c=]
DECRYPTED: [Hello World!]
```